# При создании образа docker выскакивает ошибка, что я пытаюсь скопировать несуществующую директорию

Tags: reactjs, docker

Есть простое приложение на React(Nextjs) и вот такой файл Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx AS server
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Когда я пытаюсь создать образ на последней строке возникает ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверьте, есть ли у вас `/app/build` в образе `builder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я невнимательный! Я совсем забыл о том, что build-директория в next называется ".next", а не "build"